# Easy file format for niche text printing

Tags: c, image, text, printing, pdf-generation

I have ahead of me a fairly specific task, and I was hoping someone on this site can give me the benefit of their experience

I have a text file somewhere with some 17000 lines of text. This text will need to be printed very specifically on around 80 double sided pages. These pages will then be cut into several pieces, and bound into small books (hey, it's a hobby!) This means I need to have text placed very specifically on the page. (I am also toying with the idea of having text cut off mid letter in one place and continued elsewhere)

Note that I have done this before, by manually placing text using a word processor. However, the sheer magnitude of this project really requires programming. I have thought about making some PNG files (which is easy enough to do), but I do not know how nicely they will look when printed. I have also briefly looked at some standard document file formats (like doc and pdf) and it looks like it'll take a long time before I can learn these last.

Does anyone happen to have any helpful tips, or at least know the best file format to use for such a project?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best recommendation I'd give is to use C to parse the input and generate a latex document, which is in turn used to generate a pdf for printing. Although it might seem more complicated, latex is much more flexible when it comes to typesetting placing manually the text in a bmp file for example (basically, latex is a language that consist of a set of rules to specify where and how a text should be printed).

Comment: I have found a good way to accomplish this using the LaTeX graphicsx package (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229222/change-location-of-increasing-text-length#229286)

Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Paul92 mentioned LaTex which is one option I'd consider.  The learning curve can be quite steep but it will undoubtedly do a nice job with your text if you're willing to fuss with it.

If you're feeling a bit more 'rough and ready' you might consider [markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown).  It will keep the source text a bit more readable, and there are some reasonable options for getting from markdown to a nice print out.